How can I check which platform is logged in from spring boot?
How can I check which platform is logged in from spring boot?
Manager can only log in from the web. Student can only log in from mobile.
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestBody LoginUserDTO loginUserDto) {
    User authenticatedUser = authService.signIn(loginUserDto);

    if (Role.MANAGER.equals(authenticatedUser.getRole()) && "mobile".equals(loginUserDto.getPlatform())) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("Manager can only log in via web.");
    }

    if ((Role.TEACHER.equals(authenticatedUser.getRole()) || Role.GUARDIAN.equals(authenticatedUser.getRole()))
            && "web".equals(loginUserDto.getPlatform())) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("Teachers and students can only log in via mobile.");
    }
    String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(authenticatedUser.getUsername(),authenticatedUser.getRole());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(jwtToken);
}

Is it right to make a solution like this?

I recommend not to check in the controller, instead you can create an Interceptor to do this
first step will be to create a service to detect the device type from user-agent header (DeviceService):
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

public boolean isMobileDevice() {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
        
        // Common mobile identifiers in User-Agent string
        String[] mobileDevices = {"android", "iphone", "ipad", "ipod", "blackberry", "windows phone", "opera mini", "mobile"};

        for (String device : mobileDevices) {
            if (userAgent.contains(device)) {
                return true; // It's a mobile device
            }
        }
        return false; // It's a web client
}

next is to create your interceptor:
@Component
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceService deviceService;
    
    @Autowired
    private authService authService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Boolean isMobile = deviceService.isMobileDevice();
        User authenticatedUser = authService.getAuthenticatedUser();

        // Check for platform restrictions based on the role
        if (Role.MANAGER.equals(authenticatedUser.getRole()) && isMobile) {
            //throw exception
        }

        if ((Role.TEACHER.equals(authenticatedUser.getRole()) || Role.GUARDIAN.equals(authenticatedUser.getRole())) && !isMobile) {
            //throw exception 
        }
        //otherwise the request will be processed normally
        return true;
    }
}

a second option would be to inject the DeviceService into your controller and do the check there, but that means you will check only on the login not on every request.
